# database error help, debugging

Tags: php, database

```
<?php
include('DBconnect.php');

if(isset($_POST['submit']))
{
    $password=trim($_POST['password']);
    $password2=trim($_POST['password2']);

    if($password==true && $password1==true)
    {
        $changepass = mysqli_query($mysqli,"UPDATE nweth1_firstdb SET Password = '$password' WHERE ID = ".$_SESSION["ID"]) or die(mysql_error());
        $q1 = mysqli_fetch_array($changepass);

        if ((strlen($password)) > 6) 
        {
                    // Password meets requirements
                    if ($password == $password2) 
                    {
                        //Passwords match, update the password in the database
                    }
                    else 
                    {
                    echo "<p id = 'err'>Incorrect username and password</p>";
                    }

        }
        else 
        {
            echo "<p id = 'err'>Incorrect username and password</p>";      

        }
    }
}    ?>
```

I cannot figure out the problem to this simple change password query.
Is it because of .$_SESSION["ID"]....maybe that is wrong.

if that is wrong how can I change password for that user that is logged on. it has  to indicate the current user

Comment: `$password==true` ? what do you want?

Comment: when the user updates the password it will update the database

Comment: do you mean `!empty($password)` ?

Comment: i have session_start();
include('DBconnect.php'); in original code. everything seems right to me. any ideas

Comment: For one thing, you need to change this `if($password==true && $password1==true)` to `if($password==true && $password2==true)` since you have `$password2=trim($_POST['password2']);`

Comment: great catch about password2. however, it still does not work

Comment: At this point, you need to use `var_dump()` with the elements at play. For example `var_dump($_SESSION);` and see how you can use a variable to define `$_SESSION["ID"]` and see if you replace `$_SESSION["ID"]` with an existing `ID` from your DB then see what the output will be.

Comment: How are you defining `$_SESSION["ID"]` to start with? I use a similar method for logins where I define it like this `$userName = mysqli_real_escape_string($db,$_POST['username']);` <= before `session_start();` then after `session_start();` `$_SESSION['ID'] = mysqli_real_escape_string($db,$_POST['username']);`

Comment: and your query would be `$changepass = mysqli_query($mysqli,"UPDATE nweth1_firstdb SET Password = '$password' WHERE ID = '" . $_SESSION['userName'] . "' LIMIT 1") or die(mysql_error());` you have a missing `"` btw in your existing query. I also suggest you don't include `session_start();` inside with your DB connection file. It may need to be include elsewhere. Sessions are very tricky.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't have a `session_start()` on your PHP code.

Add it like

```
<?php
session_start();//<-- Here
include('DBconnect.php');

//.... rest of code ......
```

Answer (score 0):

$password**2**=trim($_POST['password2']);

and then $password**1**==true

typo?

Comment: taking the    
 if($password==true && $password1==true) does not make the code work.

Comment: I think $password1 is undefined

Answer (score 0):

You have to start the Session.

```
session_start();
```